# Variable formatting check in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, variables, solaris

I have a real simple script to update a table based on a flat file but am concerend as the list keeps getting longer and longer a non valid formatted variable will get introduced and cause issues.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
file1=file.csv

while read mac loc; do

dbaccess modemdb <<EndOfUpdate 2>/dev/null
UPDATE profile 
SET localization= '$loc' 
WHERE mac_address = '$mac';
EndOfUpdate

done <"$file1"
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

The file contents are as such.

```
12:BF:20:1B:D3:22,RED-1234
12:BF:20:2D:FF:1B,BLUE-1234
12:BF:20:ED:74:0D,RED-9901
12:BF:20:02:69:7C,GREEN-4321
12:BF:20:02:6B:42,BROWN
12:BF:20:ED:74:0D,BLACK
```

What I am having difficulty with is how can I set a format check of the $mac and $loc variables so if they don't match it stops running. the $loc can be any 19 digits so just need to make sure its not null and not longer. The mac address needs to be not null and in the format as in the file. I found reference in another post to this check but not sure how to integrate.

```
`[[ "$MAC_ADDRESS" =~ "^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$" ]]`
```

Looking for help on how to create the validations.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check MAC address with regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=file.csv

while IFS="," read mac loc; do
  if [[ "$mac" =~ ^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$ ]]; then
    dbaccess modemdb <<EndOfUpdate 2>/dev/null
UPDATE profile 
SET localization= '$loc' 
WHERE mac_address = '$mac';
EndOfUpdate
  else
    echo "Error: $mac"
  fi
done <"$file1"
```

Your regex is for bash only a string if you use quotation marks.